# Calculate x and y coords for bullet trajectory - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I've looked high and low but nothing seems to fit quite what I'm doing. I need to calculate x and y coordinates for a bullets trajectory then plot them on Chart.js.

A bullet fired from (0, 5) will hit a target at (250, 5). The problem lies in graphing it correctly on the trajectory in between (x is yards, y is feet).

I can successfully calculate the trajectory of the bullet and bullet drop without hitting the target, but I'm not able to get the launch angle accounted for so that the bullet hits the target at x distance.

This is mainly where I've gotten my calculations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile

My app looks like this:

[image: My apps graph]

Here's what I have so far:

```
calcTrajectory() {

// get target distance - passed in

// get launch angle to hit target at that distance
let x = this.distance;
let y = this.height;
let g = 10.733; // gravity in yds
let v = this.velocity / 3; // velocity in yds
let angle = Math.atan(
  Math.pow(v, 2) + Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(v, 4) - g * ((g * x * x) + (2 * y * v * v)
    ))
  /
  (g * x)
);

// graph x y coords based on target distance, launch angle, and bullet drop
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let time = (i * 100) / v;
  let bulletY: number = Math.sin(angle - (Math.PI / 2)) * v;
  let dropVal = ((10.733 / 2) * Math.pow(time, 2)) * 3;

  console.log('Bullet Y:', bulletY);

  this.myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.push({
      x: (i * 100),
      y: parseInt(this.height) + bulletY - dropVal
    });
  });

  // update chart
  this.myChart.update();
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: clarified question and added a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove all of the Angular/Typescript stuff, but you should be able to run the below code and paste the output into a graphing program and verify it. What I'm doing is calculating the angle required to travel the distance input, then calculating the x and y vectors of the initial velocity. Then you can just multiply those by a timestep to get points that you can plot. If you want more granular points, just increase the step variable.

```js
const calcTrajectory = (distance, height, velocity)=> {

  // get target distance - passed in

  // get launch angle to hit target at that distance
  let x = distance;
  let y = height;
  let g = 10.733; // gravity in yds
  let v = velocity / 3; // velocity in yds
  let angle = Math.asin((x*g)/(v*v));
  let step = 100;
  let xVelocity = v * Math.cos(angle);
  let yVelocity = v * Math.sin(angle)
  // graph x y coords based on target distance, launch angle, and bullet drop

  let data = {x:[], y:[]}
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let time = (i / step);
    data.x.push(time*xVelocity)
    data.y.push(time* yVelocity)
    yVelocity -= (g/step)
  }
console.log(data);
}

calcTrajectory(250, 0, 2024.43)
```